# How to query a file name using URI ruby matchine platform_version and machine (x86_64

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

This does not work well, as sed does not recognized by Chef during client run, I am not sure why  .. still there.

`` def vbox_file
      shell_out("curl -sS http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.26 | grep -i virtualbox | grep -i el#{platform_version} | grep -i `uname -m` | sed 's/^.*>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/'").run_command.stdout
    end ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-answer, don't do this in shell code. Use Ruby:

```
def vbox_file
  Chef::HTTP::Simple.new('http://download.virtualbox.org/').get('/virtualbox/5.1.26')[/href="(.*?el#{node['platform_version'][0]}.*?#{node['kernel']['machine']}.*?)", 1]
end
```

Or something like that, tweak the regex as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just failing because it can't find sed; then you probably just need to include the full path for sed on your system.

On my system it is located at "/bin/sed", but you can run the command "which sed" to find out where it is on your system.